# Parsing form submitted values - D7

Tags: forms

Could anyone please point out where I might be doing something wrong? I can't seem to capture the form values to manipulate them when this form is submitted.

```
   function admin_score_table_block_view($delta = '') {
      //The $delta parameter tells us which block is being requested.
        switch ($delta) {
            case 'admin_score_table':

                $block['subject'] = t('Admin Editable Score Table');
                $block['content'] = '';
                global $user;

            $form = drupal_get_form('admin_scores');

            $block['content'] = $form;

        break;
    }
    return $block;
}


function admin_scores($form) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
        $node = node_load($nid = $node->nid);

        $programmetmp = $node->field_sportevent_cd;
        $programme = $programmetmp['und'][0];
    }

    $form['#tree'] = 1;

    $result = db_query("SELECT cdt.entity_id AS nid FROM field_data_field_team_corpdec AS cdt WHERE cdt.field_team_corpdec_nid = " . $programme['nid']);
    foreach($result as $row){
        $team = node_load($row->nid);

        $form[$team->nid]['nid'] = array(
            '#type' => 'hidden',
            '#value' => $team->nid,
        );
        $form[$team->nid]['team'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#value' => $team->title,
            '#title' => 'Team',
            '#attributes' => array('class' => 'field-team'),
            '#name' => 'team[' . $team->nid . ']'
        );
        $form[$team->nid]['score'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#value' => '',
            '#title' => 'Score',
            '#attributes' => array('class' => 'field-score'),
            '#name' => 'score[' . $team->nid . ']'
        );
    }

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Save scores',
    );

    return $form;
}


function admin_scores_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    var_dump($form_id);

}
```

Comment: try `var_dump($form_state["values"]);`

Comment: off topic: in D7 you should use the new db layer. Read [this](http://drupal.org/node/310075) for more info.

Comment: or at least you could use the placeholders: `db_query("SELECT cdt.entity_id AS nid FROM field_data_field_team_corpdec AS cdt WHERE cdt.field_team_corpdec_nid = :nid", array(":nid" =>  $programme['nid']));`

Comment: I agree with @MariusIlie. It's bad form to inject dynamic values into a SQL query, as it could lead to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is called `admin_scores()` but your submit function is called `admin_scores_form_submit()`...this isn't Drupal's naming convention so your submit handler will never be executed.

Either change the name of your submit handler:

```
function admin_scores_submit($form, &$form_state) {

}
```

Or add your non-standard submit handler in the form itself:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'admin_scores_form_submit';
```

Also the signature you're using for your form function is slightly wrong, in Drupal 7 it's like this:

```
function admin_scores($form, &$form_state) {
```

Comment: was facing a similar problem, this helped. does our new submit handler override the normal submit procedures ? and how can we make sure that our code in the submit handler is executed last of all the other normal submit procedures defined for that node ? 
eg I want the article to be added into the DBS and then only run my custom code in the submit handler.